# Need program to multiply numbers user input when user is determining how many numbers they will input

Tags: c++

I need to be able find the multiplication of all numbers entered by user.  I know how to do this when I told the program how many numbers are going to be entered however in this program the users is telling the program how many numbers they are entering.  I also need help making the average a floating point number.  For example if user inputs 1, 1, 1, 1, and 0 average should be 0.8 not 0.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int p, N = 0.0, sum =0;
float average = 0.0;

int main(){
    cout<<"Enter the number of integers you want to enter: ";
    cin>>N;
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        cout<<"enter a number: ";
        cin>>p;
        sum += p;
    }
    cout<<"The sum is "<<sum<<"\nThe average is "<<sum/N<<"\n";
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem with the input? Are you sure this is the first time this is asked about? The results of `sum/N` being rounded certain _is_ asked and answered **many** times! (hint: the result of integer division is an integer)

Comment: I don't know how to do the multiplication part.

Answer (score 0):

To enable users to input different numbers of values, you can let users to input all numbers in one line separated by spaces. Use `getline()` to load all numbers and then pass them into `vector<int>`:

```
string str;
getline(cin, str);

// read all numbers, stored them in vector<int> numbers
vector<int> numbers;
istringstream ss(str);
int num;
while(ss >> num)
{
    numbers.push_back(num);
}

// now you have all numbers, do whatever you want
cout << numbers.size() << " numbers in total" << endl;  
// ... ...
```

Check out [Ideone](http://ideone.com/mAQ1wy) for the full code.